# how to parse a file for a specified condition in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse a text file in C#. i want to extract the line number where "Rows_affected" value is greater than 500.

here's a sample of my text file..

```
Query_time: 0.000268  Lock_time: 0.000097  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 38  Rows_affected: 0    Rows_read: 1
Query_time: 0.000308  Lock_time: 0.000115  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 38  Rows_affected: 500  Rows_read: 0
Query_time: 0.000169  Lock_time: 0.000057  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 38  Rows_affected: 300  Rows_read: 0
Query_time: 0.000296  Lock_time: 0.000111  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 38  Rows_affected: 50   Rows_read: 0
Query_time: 0.000238  Lock_time: 0.000081  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 38  Rows_affected: 1    Rows_read: 0
Query_time: 0.000318  Lock_time: 0.000110  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 38  Rows_affected: 600  Rows_read: 1
```

this is my code...

```
int lineNumb = 0;
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)) {
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
        lineNumb++;
        if (line.StartsWith("# Query_time:")) {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(line.Split(':')[5].Split(' ')[1]);
            if (value > 500) {
                listBox1.Items.Add(lineNumb.ToString() + " > " + value.ToString()); 
            }
```

---

```
int lineNumb = 0;
        using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lineNumb++;
                if (line.StartsWith("# Query_time:"))
                {
                    int value = Convert.ToInt32(line.Split(':')[5].Split(' ')[1]);
                    if (value > 500)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(lineNumb.ToString() + " > "  + value.ToString());
                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Line number or numbers?

Comment: Is this guaranteed fixed format - will the "Rows_affected: " text always be followed by a number?

Comment: Is this file tab-delimited?

Comment: Formatted your code a bit (pending peer review). You seem to be missing a few `}` in your code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using linq then something like

```
static void Main()
{
    var lines = ReadAllLines(@"path\to\your\file.txt");

    var lineNumbers = lines.Where(l => Criteria(l))
                           .Select((s, i) => i);

    foreach (var i in lineNumbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Criteria met on line " + i);
    }
}

static bool Criteria(string s)
{
    int i = int.Parse(Regex.Match(s, "(?<=Rows_affected: )\d+").Value);

    return i > 500;
}
```

Comment: Did you miss .Value at the end of the Regex.Match?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression on each line to identify the rows affected. Then use an integer value to identify the line number.

```
string filename = "yourfilename";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<rowsaffected>(?<=Rows_affected:\s)[0-9]*)");
int lineNumber = 1;            
using(TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    while(line != null)
    {
        Match m = r.Match(line);
        int rowsaffected = int.Parse(m.Groups["rowsaffected"].Value);
        if(rowsaffected > 500)
        {                        
            // do whatever you want with your linenumber here.
        }
        lineNumber++;
        line = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you addressing the need to find `> 500`?

Comment: Jesus, hold your horses. I was finishing something else while typing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here I have the simple solution, that is read line by line remove the '  ' with  ' ' and then split the line , that value will be at 9th index in splitted string array, simple convert it into int and compare with value 500.

if it's greater it will return true and you will see, line number printed on to console window.

below is the data saved in file:

```
Query_time: 0.000268  Lock_time: 0.000097  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 38  Rows_affected: 0    Rows_read: 1
Query_time: 0.000308  Lock_time: 0.000115  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 38  Rows_affected: 500  Rows_read: 0
Query_time: 0.000169  Lock_time: 0.000057  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 38  Rows_affected: 300  Rows_read: 0
Query_time: 0.000296  Lock_time: 0.000111  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 38  Rows_affected: 50   Rows_read: 0
Query_time: 0.000238  Lock_time: 0.000081  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 38  Rows_affected: 1    Rows_read: 0
Query_time: 0.000318  Lock_time: 0.000110  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 38  Rows_affected: 600  Rows_read: 1
```

//Here is the actual code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace LineNumber
{
    class Program
    {
        static System.IO.StreamReader sr;
        static int linenumber = 1;
        static string line;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
           {
                sr = new StreamReader("data.dat");
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (FindNumber(line) == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Line Number : " + linenumber++);
                    }
                    else
                        linenumber++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("End of File");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        static bool FindNumber(string line)
        {
            string[] linesplit;
            try
            {
                if (line.Length == 0)
                    return false;
                else
                {
                    line = line.Replace("  "," ");
               }
                linesplit = line.Split(' ');
                if(int.Parse(linesplit[9]) > 500)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Screen Shot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Taking the file format at face value, a simple option would to be to search for the "Rows_affected: " string on each line, then parse the text behind it.

```
        string row = <<row from your file>>                

        int startPosition = row.IndexOf("Rows_affected: ") + "Rows_affected: ".Length;
        int endPosition = row.IndexOf(" ", startPosition);

        int numberAffected = Int32.Parse(row.Substring(startPosition, endPosition - startPosition));
```

You can then check numberAffected and make a note of it as you wish. Error checking omitted for brevity.

Comment: If you're comfortable with LINQ, I would say the answer T I posted is better than mine.